# Data to dendrogram and back

Tags: python, scipy, dendrogram

I have a feeling this is a very simply question but I cannot figure it out.

I have a small set of trajectories which I am trying to cluster using scipi hcluster.

[image: a small set of trajectories]

I have been successful in this regard

```
    from hcluster import linkage, dendrogram

    l = linkage(matrix)
    d = dendrogram(l)
    show()
```

[image]

However I cannot figure out how to map the colors assigned by the dendrogram back to the original trajectories. The dendrogram has the following keys ['ivl', 'dcoord', 'leaves', 'color_list', 'icoord']. According to the documentation 'ivl' is the set of labels that are printed at the bottom of the figure, these are impossible to read because the font is tiny.

I have tried the following

```
    for index, label in enumerate(d['ivl']):
        print 'trajectory #%s has color %s' % (label, d['color_list'][index])
```

However this blows up because there is one less color in color_list than labels in ivl. When I look at the dendrogram I can clearly see 2 greens, 2 reds, 3 magenta, etc. However the dendrogram tells me otherwise

```
    from collections import Counter        
    Counter(d['color_list'])
    Counter({'y': 68, 'b': 18, 'm': 2, 'c': 1, 'g': 1, 'r': 1})
```

So finally my question. What is this awful structure and how do I actually get the color assigned to each trajectory by the dendrogram?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and found your post.  Hopefully you've found the answer by now as it's been months, but in case anyone else also comes across this problem:
You can use the function fcluster to get the clusters:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster

```
fcluster(Z,0.7*max(Z[:,2]),'distance')
```

should match the fcluster parameters to the default dendrogram parameters.

Hope this works!